# How do you design a codable JSON field which can be either an empty string or an int

Tags: json, swift, field, codable

How do you handle a field of a codable struct from JSON which can be either an empty string or an int?  I tried using the data type any but that does not conform to codable.  I think that if it does not have a value then it returns an empty string or otherwise, it returns an int.  I am using Swift 4 and XCode 9.  Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the type of this field in your Swift type? `Int?`

Comment: Yes, I would like to use an int for that field.  If it is an empty string I would like to default it to 0 if possible or nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really would suggest changing that web service to return values consistently (and if there is no value for the integer type, don't return anything for that key).

But if you're stuck with this design, you will have to write your own `init(from:)` which gracefully handles the failure to parse the integer value. E.g.:

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        do {
            age = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
        } catch {
            age = nil
        }
    }

}
```

I'd also advise against using `0` as a sentinel value for "no integer value provided". This is what optionals are for.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I guess I will have to take a long way round because I don't have access to change the server.

Comment: Lol. Yeah, we've all been there, saddled with some questionable interface managed by others.