# Swift 4 Codable - Bool or String values

Tags: json, swift, codable

Looking for some input as to how you would handle the scenario I recently ran into.

I have been using Swift 4s Codable with success but today noticed a crash that I didn't expect.  The API that I am working with, says it returns a `boolean` for the key `manage_stock`.

My stubbed struct looks like:

```
struct Product: Codable {
    var manage_stock: Bool?
}
```

That works fine, the problem is that the API **sometimes** returns a `string` instead of a `boolean`.

Because of this, my decode fails with:

```
Expected to decode Bool but found a string/data instead.
```

The string only ever equals `"parent"` and I want it to equate to `false`.

I am also fine with changing my struct to `var manage_stock: String?` if that makes things easier to bring the JSON data in from the API.  But of course, if I change that, my error just changes to:

```
Expected to decode String but found a number instead.
```

Is there a simple way to handle this mutation or will I need to lose all the automation that `Codable` brings to the table and implement my own `init(decoder: Decoder)`.

Cheers

Comment: You have to *implement my own `init(decoder: Decoder)`*. Alternatively ask the owner of the API to send consistent data 

Comment: generally speaking, such chaotic API is supposed to be fixed inside the API, rather than patching the API's clients, because you __cannot__ patch your app for every stupid anomaly what the web-devs committed; therefore they (the API and its devs) need to be stuck with strict (optionally optional) types; could you negotiate with them instead of trying to cover their crap? because such issue __must be__ solved on the API level, not on the app level.

Comment: maybe related/useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297263/how-to-use-any-in-codable-type/48297432#48297432

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you can't always be in control of the APIs you're working with, here's one simple way to solve this with `Codable` directly, by overriding `init(from:)`:

```
struct Product : Decodable {
    // Properties in Swift are camelCased. You can provide the key separately from the property.
    var manageStock: Bool?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case manageStock = "manage_stock"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            self.manageStock = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .manageStock)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            // There was something for the "manage_stock" key, but it wasn't a boolean value. Try a string.
            if let string = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .manageStock) {
                // Can check for "parent" specifically if you want.
                self.manageStock = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) for more info on this.

Comment: That's what I thought, I'll accept this since you provided a good example.  Cheers.

Comment: great solution, mate! Thank you so much!