# Swift Codable: subclass JSONDecoder for custom behavior

Tags: json, swift, type-conversion, codable, decodable

I'm having an inconsistent API that might return either a `String` or an `Number` as a part of the JSON response.

The dates also could be represented the same way as either a `String` or a `Number`, but are always an UNIX timestamp (i.e. `timeIntervalSince1970`).

To fix the issue with the dates, I simply used a custom `JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy`:

```
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy.custom({ decoder in
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            if let doubleValue = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
                return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: doubleValue)
            } else if let stringValue = try? container.decode(String.self),
                      let doubleValue = Double(stringValue) {
                return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: doubleValue)
            }
            
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container,
                                                   debugDescription: "Unable to decode value of type `Date`")
        })
```

However, no such customization is available for the `Int` or `Double` types which I'd like to apply it for.

So, I have to resort to writing `Codable` initializers for each of the model types that I'm using.

The alternative approach I'm looking for is to subclass the `JSONDecoder` and override the `decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable` method.

In that method I'd like to "inspect" the type `T` that I'm trying to decode to and then, if the base implementation (`super`) fails, try to decode the value first to `String` and then to the `T` (the target type).

So far, my initial prototype looks like this:

```
final class CustomDecoder: JSONDecoder {
    override func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
        do {
            return try super.decode(type, from: data)
        } catch {
            if type is Int.Type {
                print("Trying to decode as a String")
                if let decoded = try? super.decode(String.self, from: data),
                   let converted = Int(decoded) {
                    return converted as! T
                }
            }
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

However, I found out that the `"Trying to decode as a String"` message is never printed for some reason, even though the control reaches the `catch` stage.

I'm happy to have that custom path only for `Int` and `Double` types, since the `T` is `Codable` and that doesn't guarantee ability to initialize a value with the `String`, however, I of course welcome a more generalized approach.

Here's the sample Playground code that I came up with to test my prototype. It can be copy-pasted directly into the Playground and works just fine.
My goal is to have both `jsonsample1` and `jsonsample2` to produce the same result.

```
import UIKit


final class CustomDecoder: JSONDecoder {
    override func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
        do {
            return try super.decode(type, from: data)
        } catch {
            if type is Int.Type {
                print("Trying to decode as a String")
                if let decoded = try? super.decode(String.self, from: data),
                   let converted = Int(decoded) {
                    return converted as! T
                }
            }
            throw error
        }
    }
}

let jsonSample1 =
"""
    {
        "name": "Paul",
        "age": "38"
    }
"""

let jsonSample2 =
"""
    {
        "name": "Paul",
        "age": 38
    }
"""

let data1 = jsonSample1.data(using: .utf8)!
let data2 = jsonSample2.data(using: .utf8)!


struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let age: Int?
}


let decoder = CustomDecoder()
let person1 = try? decoder.decode(Person.self, from: data1)
let person2 = try? decoder.decode(Person.self, from: data2)
print(person1 as Any)
print(person2 as Any)
```

What could be the reason for my `CustomDecoder` not working?

Comment: If you print `type` in your override function you will see it says Person and not Int. Probably better to implement a custom `init(from:)` for `Person`

Comment: Thanks, that's a good catch. So, looks like I have to write manual codable code for `Int` and `String` cases, unlike with the custom strategy as with Date

Comment: Having the possibility to create a date strategy makes senses since often all dates of a json message is in the same format but it would be unlikely that all Int values of a json message can be given sometimes as an Int and sometimes a String and it is of course very different to offer customisable functionality for something that can be expected to be different than to offer it for bad/low quality json which this must be considered to be,

Comment: Apparently, people who have developed Codable API haven't encountered much of the real-world APIs. It's not the first time I'm having this issue, so that I'm trying to come up with a generic solution.

Comment: @RichardTopchii Typically, the solution to having to decode "`X` or `Y`" would be to write a type which can represent an `X` or `Y`, usually an `enum`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621515/swift-4-codable-bool-or-string-values/48626223#48626223 for dealing with `.typeMismatch`; you can write an `enum` with `case string(String)` and `case number(Double)` which decodes from a `singleValueContainer`, as one value and if that fails, you try the other. That can be significantly simpler than having to subclass a `Decoder`

Comment: I don't like an `enum` solution as it complicates usage of the model type at call site, further down the application. That complexity should be hidden at the parsing layer. I ended up creating a custom `init(from Decoder` method and adding the parsing logic there.

Comment: @RichardTopchii [Using codable with value that is sometimes an Int and other times a String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47936022/2303865)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary reason that your decoder doesn't do what you expect is that you're not overriding the method that you want to be: [`JSONDecoder.decode<T>(_:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895189-decode) is the *top-level* method that is called when you call

```swift
try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data)
```

but this is *not* the method that is called internally during decoding. Given the JSON you show as an example, if we write a `Person` struct as

```swift
struct Person: Decodable {
   let name: String
   let age: Int
}
```

then the compiler will write an `init(from:)` method which looks like this:

```swift
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    age = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
}
```

Note that when we decode `age`, we are not calling a method on the decoder directly, but on a `KeyedCodingContainer` that we get from the decoder — specifically, the `Int.Type` overload of [`KeyedDecodingContainer.decode(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2921411-decode).

In order to hook into the methods that are called during decode at the middle levels of a `Decoder`, you'd need to hook into its actual container methods, which is very difficult — all of `JSONDecoder`'s containers and internals are private. In order to do this by subclassing `JSONDecoder`, you'd end up needing to pretty much reimplement the whole thing from scratch, which is significantly more complicated than what you're trying to do.

---

As suggested in a comment, you're likely better off either:

1. Writing `Person.init(from:)` manually by trying to decode both `Int.self` and `String.self` for the `.age` property and keeping whichever one succeeds, or
2. If you need to reuse this solution across many types, you can write a wrapper type to use as a property:

   ```swift
   struct StringOrNumber: Decodable {
       let number: Double

       init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
           let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
           do {
               number = try container.decode(Double.self)
           } catch (DecodingError.typeMismatch) {
               let string = try container.decode(String.self)
               if let n = Double(string) {
                   number = n
               } else {
                   throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Value wasn't a number or a string...")
               }
           }
       }
   }

   struct Person: Decodable {
       let name: String
       let age: StringOrNumber
   }
   ```
3. You can also write `StringOrNumber` as an `enum` which can hold either `case string(String)` or `case number(Double)` if knowing which type of value was in the payload was important:

   ```swift
   enum StringOrNumber: Decodable {
       case number(Double)
       case string(String)

       init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
           let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
           do {
               self = try .number(container.decode(Double.self))
           } catch (DecodingError.typeMismatch) {
               let string = try container.decode(String.self)
               if let n = Double(string) {
                   self = .string(string)
               } else {
                   throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Value wasn't a number or a string...")
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Though this isn't as relevant if you *always* need `Double`/`Int` access to the data, since you'd need to re-convert at the use site every time (and you call this out in a comment)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up using a similar solution, except instead of try-catch I've used optional decoding with `try?` and `decodeIfPresent`

Comment: Nice use of `catch` with an error case.  I always forget that possible, so thanks for the reminder :-)