# How to parse this JSON format in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, codable

I have this JSON format:

```
{
  "version":"7.0.19",
  "fields": ["ID","pm","age","pm_0","pm_1","pm_2","pm_3","pm_4","pm_5","pm_6","conf","pm1","pm_10","p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6","Humidity","Temperature","Pressure","Elevation","Type","Label","Lat","Lon","Icon","isOwner","Flags","Voc","Ozone1","Adc","CH"],
  "data":[[20,0.0,1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,97,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,null,null,null,1413,0,"Oakdale",40.603077,-111.83612,0,0,0,null,null,0.01,1]],
  "count":11880
}
```

but I cannot work out how to use a Codable protocol to parse the json response.

this would be my desired model.

```
struct Point: Codable {
    let pm2: String?
    let latitude, longitude: Double?
    let temp: String?
    let iD: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pm2 = "pm", temp = "Temperature", iD = "ID", latitude = "Lat", longitude = "Lon"
    }
}
```

Here is a URL to the json

`https://webbfoot.com/dataa.json`

Comment: So, the idea is that the order of values in `"data"` is defined by the order of fields in `"fields"`?

Comment: Yes. for example..The first row I.D. = 20, pm = 0.0 etc...

Comment: You should add to your question what the resulting model you want to get, even if you don't know how to do it

Comment: I've answered a similar question in the past, so it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61854827/968155

Comment: Blame the owner of the service for sending this pseudo-CSV format. This is extremely nonpractical to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Codable` to parse this:

```
struct Response: Decodable {

   let version: String
   let fields: [String]
   let data: [[QuantumValue?]]
   let count: Int

}
enter code here

enum QuantumValue: Decodable {

case float(Float), string(String)

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    if let int = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Float.self) {
        self = .float(float)
        return
    }

    if let string = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self) {
        self = .string(string)
        return
    }

    throw QuantumError.missingValue
}

enum QuantumError:Error {
    case missingValue
}
}
```

`QuantumValue` will handle both `Float` and `String` and `?` will handle the `null` part.

Comment: This wouldn't work since `"data"` contains both `Int` and `String` and `null`

Comment: That works, but you should clarify first with the OP what the resulting model should be. EDIT: see his latest edit

Answer (score 0):

This one is tricky and requires manual decoding. The principle would be to define a mapping between the fields you expect to decode and the properties of your object, then depending on the type of the property (`String`, `Double`, etc...), attempt to decode the data.

Second, since you have an array of points, you need some kind of container object to hold the array, for example:

```
struct Points {
    var data: [Point] = []
}
```

First, some of your model properties don't match the type in the data, e.g. `iD` is a `String`, but the data has an `Int`. For simplicity, I'll redefine your model to match the data

```
struct Point {
    var pm2: Int? = nil
    var latitude: Double? = nil
    var longitude: Double? = nil
    var temp: Int? = nil
    var iD: Int? = nil
}
```

Now, write the manual decoder for the parent container `Points`:

```
extension Points: Decodable {   
    static let mapping: [String: PartialKeyPath<Point>] = [
        "pm":          \Point.pm2,
        "Lat":         \Point.latitude,
        "Lon":         \Point.longitude,
        "Temperature": \Point.temp,
        "ID":          \Point.iD
    ]

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case fields, data }
    private struct Dummy: Decodable {} // see below why

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let fields = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .fields)
        var data = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .data)

        while !data.isAtEnd {
            var row = try data.nestedUnkeyedContainer()

            var point = Point()          
            for field in fields {

                let keyPath = Points.mapping[field]
                switch keyPath {
                case let kp as WritableKeyPath<Point, String?>:
                    point[keyPath: kp] = try row.decodeIfPresent(String.self)
                case let kp as WritableKeyPath<Point, Int?>:
                    point[keyPath: kp] = try row.decodeIfPresent(Int.self)
                case let kp as WritableKeyPath<Point, Double?>:
                    point[keyPath: kp] = try row.decodeIfPresent(Double.self)
                default:
                    // this is a hack to skip this value
                    let _ = try? row.decode(Dummy.self)
                }
            }
            self.data.append(point)
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you can decode the JSON like so:

```
let points = try JSONDecoder().decode(Points.self, from: jsonData)
let firstPoint = points.data[0]
```

Comment: I have added the URL to the question. Could you show me how this could work in your code above? Thanks

Comment: So, what you have in the URL is not quite what you had in your question. In the URL, the JSON contains multiple rows (inner arrays) of `data`, whereas the JSON in your question has a single inner row. Presumably, you'd want to decode an array of `Point`s?

Comment: Yes.. i showed only one row in my initial question, but what I really want to do is find the ID of a particular row based on its lat long proximity to the users lat long

Comment: I updated the answer to decode an array of points. Once you decode the response, you can do whatever search you need.