# How to decode Swift 5 version?

Tags: ios, swift, decode, appdelegate

[Decode base64URL to base64 -- Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499651/decode-base64url-to-base64-swift) / [Decoding JSON array with codable - Swift 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311232/decoding-json-array-with-codable-swift-5)

I tried to do it by referring to these two articles. But it's very different from what I'm trying to do.

**Other code i referenced**

```
let base64decryptData = NSMutableData(base64EncodedString: encodeBase64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.allZeros)
let decodeBase64String: NSString = NSString(data: base64decryptData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    NSLog("Base64 decoding : %@", decodeBase64String)
```

It's the most similar to what I'm trying to do, but I don't know if the grammar has changed a lot because it's a 2015 text or if I found the wrong solution, so I'm asking a question.

To summarize, I would like to decode the code like the picture into base64 and use it as a concise code. I would appreciate if you can tell me how (This is a capture of very `little of the code`.)[image]

**mycode**

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
   print( httpResponse.allHeaderFields )
                                
   guard let data = data else {return}
                
   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
   struct UserData: Codable {
          let userId: String?
          let profile: String?
   }
                    
   do {
      let userData = try decoder.decode(UserData.self, from: data)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
          ad?.paramProfile = userData.profile
          
          let base64decryptData = NSMutableData(base64EncodedString: ad?.paramProfile ?? "", options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions) // ERROR[Cannot convert value of type 'NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.Type' to expected argument type 'NSData.Base64DecodingOptions']
          let decodeBase64String: NSString = NSString(data: base64decryptData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
          print("AppDelegate - paramProfile : ",decodeBase64String )
     }

   } catch {
       print("Error:\(error)")
   }           
}
```

**AppDelegate**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var paramId: String?
    var paramProfile: String?
```

Code description: After creating a random value `UserData`, converting it to `data64` after connecting with the value in `AppDelegate`

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You need to pass the enumeration option not its type. `NSMutableData(base64Encoded: "", options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)` and the initializer parameter has been renamed to `base64Encoded` but as mentioned by Matt you should use Swift native types when coding in Swift. Just don't force unwrap the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use NSString. Do not use NSMutableData. Do not use NSLog. This is Swift, not Objective-C. Use Data.

Example of decoding a string which has been Base 64 encoded:

```
let s = "d2VsbCBob3dkeSB0aGVyZQ=="
let d = Data(base64Encoded: s)!
let s2 = String(data: d, encoding: .utf8)!
print(s2) // well howdy there
```

That may not be identically what you are trying to do (I couldn't figure out what you were trying to do), but it should get you started. Just consult the documentation on Data.

Comment: I will explain the content of the question from the beginning. I am using urlsession to communicate with the server. I want to change the long character value given by the server to the base64 decode and change it to a visually recognizable value.

Comment: This is the answer to the comment you just left.

Comment: First of all, I will refer to the Apple documentation and change it in the way you told me. Thank you

Comment: But how you do that depends on exactly what is encoded.